# How to get DataGrid row data after user has finished editing row?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I want to validate what the user has entered immediately after the user has finished entering a row in a datagrid.

What event should I be looking at, and how do I retrieve the row data? Or even better, the object it's bound to?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [RowEditEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.roweditending.aspx) event.

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  YourObject obj = e.Row.Item as YourObject;
  if (obj != null)
  {
     //see obj properties
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw that, and I see the `Row` property on `e`, but I'm still not sure how to retrieve the data entered?

Comment: It has the `DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs` which has the row data object. If you seeing weird behavior, please elaborate. (see my edit)

Comment: Ahh... `e.Row.Item` is where the data is stored... that's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 3):

1. Event RowEditEnding
2. Data should be in e.Row.DataContext/e.Row.Item

Comment: Whats the difference between DataContext and Item?

Comment: DataContext will be set if the item was generated from a ItemsSource binding on the DataGrid, in that case Item and DataContext will be identical. DataContext is used to allow binding paths relative to a given context.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having problems, I had success using:

```
DataGridCellInfo selected = YourDataGrid.SelectedCells[0];
YourObject selectedRow = selected.Item as YourObject;
```