# Data grid catch evenent after it has been edited

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to catch the status of data grid change by doing it after it has been edited, but the problem that i am having is that `row.RowState` is saying it is unmodified after the row has been edited. Also if i click on other rows below the row that i edit it will then catch the row that i edited as modified. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong or if there is a better way to do this in WPF i am new to WPF thanks everyone .

```
private void OnEndEdit(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
 {
      addDataGridDND(dgActiveProblems, true);

      foreach (DataRow row in _dtProblemList.Rows)
      {
         row.EndEdit()
         if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
         {
              passivate();
         }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674101/1522991) question:

```
private void DataGrid_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
  addDataGridDND(dgActiveProblems, true);

  foreach (DataRow row in _dtProblemList.Rows)
  {
     row.EndEdit()
     if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
     {
          passivate();
     }
  }
}
```

Use the `RowEditEnding` event.